# Benchmarking performance using Instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa

I am looking for some advice on how to use Instruments' Time Profiler to enhance a specific operation. I have a paging scroll view that loads its content on demand. As a new page is scrolled to, another is loaded two pages to the right. This happens when the current page is scrolled 50% of screen, and on slower devices the loading is enough of a bottle neck that it interrupts the smoothness of the scroll. The scroll feels like it pauses very briefly at the 50% pint and then jumps back into action.

I should note that there is no network component to my application, so the bottle neck is not while data is fetched - it is all in the loading of the new view.

As I work on improving this, I need to benchmark the transition so I can evaluate the effect of my enhancements. Having watched the WWDC sessions, I understand the basics of the time profiler but I'm not confident I am looking at the right thing.

I am running the instrument and then executing the scroll. I see the expected spike in CPU activity. I am then selecting the spike and looking at the symbol names. As you can see below, when I hide system libraries and show Obj-C I am dealing a brief 90% spike with 81.0 ms of running time.

[image]

My confusion comes when I drill down to my code. I find that one of the largest contributors (23 ms) is a small routine that just uses `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`. Not much I can do about that one. Other times the root cause will me using CGRectInset - a few more milliseconds. I guess I expected to see more related to image use or something like that.

I guess I don't know if I'm benchmarking the right things. Am I really meant to try and reduce my 6ms operations down to 5ms and expect to see a difference? Am I looking at the right tools to diagnose my problem?

Any tips or instructions on what to measure and where to focus my efforts would be really valued.

Comment: If the array sorting is taking the time, that's where you should focus your efforts. Why are you sorting the array then? Can it be pre-sorted? Does it have to be an array?

Comment: And it looks like you're doing the right thing as far as your instruments use is concerned. That method and cellForRowAtIndexPath seems to be where most of your time is going. Double-click to show the actual hotspots in your source code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I have a core data class with a set of items. For convenience, I added an orderedItems method to that class. When I need the text for a cell, for example, I use the orderedItems to find the correct item. Maybe I can shave off a few ms by caching this on the class and somehow updating it whenever the items change.

Comment: You could perhaps keep the data for the previous, current and next pages in memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I am already doing that. I still need to load next + 1 on scrolling though to keep up with the user's scrolling.

Comment: What about loading your "next" view in the background?

Comment: You mean on a background thread? Or just before it is required? If the latter, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, on a background thread so that it does not block the main thread while it us running.

Comment: My understanding is that I can't do anything UI-relared on a background thread?

Comment: Correct, but you can load the data in the background.  You actually display it on the main thread though.

Comment: Assuming you're using the pagingEnabled property of your UIScrollView, rather than loading the next image 50% of the way, why not load it when the scroll view ends decelerating. There's a better chance the user will no be interacting with it at this point and so, wouldn't notice the lag.

Comment: I considered this. However, the user does not end decelerating on each page if they drag through a few pages. I will probably add it anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using grand central dispatch to do as much non-UI work (fetching, sorting, selecting etc) as much as possible on a background thread.  This will leverage the power of multi-cpu machines and get you off the main thread faster.  Only using main thread for ui work as needed.